# Scrapy : login request and crawling, passing item into multiple pages

Tags: python, django, callback, request, scrapy

I have succesfully merge django and scrapy, and want to persist my items object into database.
Saving works fine, but whithout all the element.

I'm pretty new on python, scrapy and django and I figure I miss something, but can't solve it.

Here is my spider code :

```
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from datacrowdscrapy.items import DatacrowdItem

class DatacrowdSpider(BaseSpider):
   name = 'datacrowd'
   start_urls = ['https://www.exemple.com/login']

   def parse(self, response):
        parsed = [FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={
                'login': 'email@gmail.com',
                'password': 'password'
            },
            callback=self.after_login)]

        return parsed

   def after_login(self, response):
       # check login succeed before going on
       if "authentication failed" in response.body:
           self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
           return

       selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       investmentsLinks = selector.select('//a[contains(@class, "myClass")]/@href').extract()
       for link in investmentsLinks:
           curDatacrowdItem = XPathItemLoader(item=DatacrowdItem(), response=response)
           curDatacrowdItem.add_value('url', link)
           curRequest = Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_investments, meta={'item': curDatacrowdItem})
           yield curRequest


   def parse_investments(self, response):
       selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       curDatacrowdItem = response.meta['item']

       # Details
       details = selector.select('//td/div[contains(@class, "myClass")]/text()').extract()
       curDatacrowdItem.add_value('someVal', details[0].strip())
       /* ... */

       # Get nbInvestors
       investorLink = selector.select('//ul[contains(@id, "myId")]/li/@onclick').re(r'window.location.href=\'(http.+/data.+)\'')
       curRequest = Request(url=investorLink[0], callback=self.parse_investors, meta={'item': curDatacrowdItem})
       yield curRequest


       # Get last company details
       detailsLink = selector.select('//ul[contains(@id, "myData")]/li/@onclick').re(r'window.location.href=\'(http.+/company-details.+)\'')
       curRequest = Request(url=detailsLink[0], callback=self.parse_details, meta={'item': curDatacrowdItem})
       yield curRequest

   def parse_investors(self, response):
       selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       curDatacrowdItem = response.meta['item']
       nbInvestors = len(selector.select('//ul/li[contains(@class, "myClass")]'))
       curDatacrowdItem.add_value('nbInvestors', nbInvestors)
       return curDatacrowdItem

   def parse_details(self, response):
       selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       curDatacrowdItem = response.meta['item']

       # Company name
       name = selector.select('//div[contains(@class, "myClass")]/h2/text()').extract()
       curDatacrowdItem.add_value('name', name[0].strip())
       item = curDatacrowdItem.load_item()
       item.save() # Here I'm persisiting datas
       return item
```

I get an error log like that :

```
[datacrowd] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem or None, got 'XPathItemLoader' in <GET http://www.exemple.com/url/slug>
```

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong ?

Cheers,

Snite

Comment: Can't edit for courtesy :/

Comment: Could you please give us the complete trace?

Comment: I think your `parse_investors()` callback should return `return curDatacrowdItem.load_item()`. You are passing `XPathItemLoader` instances in your `meta` object under key "item"; I suggest you rename that key to "item_loader" to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because you are yielding an XPathItemLoader and not an Item.

In your method "after_login", you're adding an XPathItemLoader objects in the meta, which you try to yield later.

Use the load_item method to return the item.

```
meta={'item': curDatacrowdItem.load_item()}
```

You should rename your variables to avoid these mistakes :)

Comment: Yes, it was the point.
After that, I have to convert curDatacrowdItem.add_value('url', link) into curDatacrowdItem['url'] = link to work